# When using the Burning Scimitar, must you remove exactly 2 meeples?

Tags: five-tribes

When playing the Artisans of Naqala expansion for Five Tribes, an interesting scenario came up. One player wanted to use the Burning Scimitar magic item and remove 1 meeple to empty a tile and claim it. The wording on the card indicates

> Remove two meeples of any color(s) from a Tile of your choice...

Does this wording mean that you must remove exactly 2 meeples, or can you remove up to 2 meeples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can remove just one meeple.

The designer Bruno Cathala answered this question himself on BGG questions [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1391723/can-burning-scimitar-kill-only-one-meeple), [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1822087/burning-scimitar), and [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1360827/iblis-djinn)